# Swift 4 prepare(for segue:) not being called

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a split view controller and its not calling my prepare(for segue:) method when I click on an item in my table view. Here is my prepare(for segue:) method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print("Here");
        if segue.identifier == "showPOsDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! POsDetail
                controller.detailItem = object
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is a screenshot of my storeyboard. I have no idea why this method is not being called.

[image]

Ive been trying to figure with out for days now and I am super duper frustrated that its not working.

Here is my full Master Controller:

```
import UIKit

class POsMaster: UITableViewController {

    var POsDetailController: POsDetail? = nil
    var objects = [Any]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(insertNewObject(_:)))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
        if let split = splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            POsDetailController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? POsDetail
        }

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc
    func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any) {
        objects.insert(NSDate(), at: 0)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

    // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print("Here");
        if segue.identifier == "showPOsDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! POsDetail
                controller.detailItem = object
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "POCell", for: indexPath)

        let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
        cell.textLabel!.text = object.description
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: @user979311 have you checked with breakpoints ? Is call even going inside?

Comment: Yes I have, its not going inside the method at all.

Comment: at what point its not going inside ?? Do you have any value here -: if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{}? Or is it nil?Or is it not even giving output for this ? print("Here");

Comment: I am not even getting the output for print("Here");

Comment: Where in your code are you pushing the new `UIViewController`? The problem might be in the way you are doing it. Are you using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` method from `UITableViewDelegate`?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you set the segue from the “Selection group” or from “Accessory Action”? Because you have to set it from Selection group.

Comment: @StefanStefanov I updated my question with my full code.

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro "have you set the segue from the “Selection group” or from “Accessory Action”? " How would I know? I set the segue on the Cell

Comment: When you connect your cell with the detail view controller you can choose the type of your segue in a pop up like when you connect an action to a UIButton

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro How can I tell / do that?

Comment: Sorry I mean on Storyboard, when you have connected your segue ;)

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro That worked! If you put it into an answer, ill accept that SOB, Thank you very much

Comment: @user979331 done! You are welcome! Happy to help ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect your segue in storyboard a pop up opens and you have to check if you have set your segue from the `Selection group`, instead of the `Accessory group`, the ***Selection group*** connection will call your `prepareForSegue:` method.

Comment: Great Answer Bud!

Comment: hey man, sorry for asking, I did my segue from my storyboard but i didn't get your answer, and I still have this issue, can you please give me more information?

Comment: Hi @ArashAfshar you are right I will update my answer to make it clearer, thank you for pointing it out. Anyway you can find an explanation in the question comments ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the isUserEnteractionEnabled is set to true.

Seems like that could be the only reason.

Comment: @user979331 do you see the cell being selected(it should turn darker)?